# Does Azure Application Gateway Support Azure App Servers Backends?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, load-balancing, high-availability, azure-application-gateway

I would like to setup my apps with High Availability and Security in mind and thinking of using the Azure Application Gateway to provide WAF and Load Balancing (Layer-7) capabilities.  I couldn't find any concrete information from official documentation that this is a supported setup (using App Service as AG backends).  The official documentation only states VMs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/overview

Here's a simplified architecture.

[image]

Does anyone have first-hand experience with this setup?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Application gateway support app services as the backend. If you want to use the High Availability of app service, you could target two app services in the same backend pool, then the APP GW frontend receiving traffic will go round-robin to the backends in the pool. You could get more details from [Configure App Service with Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/configure-web-app-portal)

If you just want to host multi-site in the same Azure application gateway, then each site will direct to each backend pool, you could follow this [tutorial: Create and configure an application gateway to host multiple web sites using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/create-multiple-sites-portal)